# I am getting an error in SSIS like failed validation and returned validation status as VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am getting an error in SSIS like failed validation and returned validation status as VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA in data flow task .It is having oledb source and flat file destination, I tried many ways like making delay validation true but still no luck , re connected source and destination still no luck. Could anyone please help me?

I tried many ways like making delay validation true but still no luck , re connected source and destination still no luck. Could anyone please help me?